# Scraping articles share count

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I’m scraping  articles share count of a particular website using [this](https://graph.facebook.com/?id=URL) and python but it has limit and It’s quite slow. Do I need application access token or user aces token to get this data through facebook API? And also how do I authenticate? Should I append the token in the url? My code:

```
try:
    OpenGraphURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?id=' +str(adres)
    fbComments = requests.get(OpenGraphURL, timeout=30)
    data = json.loads(fbComments.text)
    shary = str(data["share"]['share_count'])
    print(shary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Should I append the token in the url" - Yes, of course:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=' + str(adres) + '&access_token=' + str(accessToken)
```

Try with an App Token, User Tokens are not valid forever.

More about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/